# Using react-hooks find total and print average

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

During on click on save, I am getting nothing in console. I would like to find the `total` of all values and then calculate the `average`

demo added here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-pike-ljnfk?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState({
    shooting: "",
    dribbling: "",
    ballcontrol: "",
    sprinting: "",
    fitness: ""
  });
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const onChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    //setRating({ ...rating, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    const ratingValues = {
      ...rating,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    setRating(ratingValues);
    calculateAvgRating(ratingValues);
  };

  const calculateAvgRating = ratingValues => {
    const {
      shooting,
      dribbling,
      ballcontrol,
      sprinting,
      fitness
    } = ratingValues;
    const newTotal =
      parseInt(shooting) +
      parseInt(dribbling) +
      parseInt(ballcontrol) +
      parseInt(sprinting) +
      parseInt(fitness);

    const finalAvg = newTotal / 5;
    setTotal(finalAvg);
    console.log("GGGGG:" + total);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="soccerFeatures">
          <label>Shooting:</label>
          <input name="shooting" onChange={e => setRating(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div className="soccerFeatures">
          <label>Dribbling:</label>
          <input name="dribbling" onChange={e => setRating(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div className="soccerFeatures">
          <label>Ball Control:</label>
          <input name="ballcontrol" onChange={e => setRating(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div className="soccerFeatures">
          <label>Sprinting:</label>
          <input name="sprinting" onChange={e => setRating(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div className="soccerFeatures">
          <label>Fitness:</label>
          <input name="fitness" onChange={e => setRating(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="submitButton" onClick={onChange}>
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Change  
`<input name="shooting" onChange={e => setRating(e.target.value)} />` 
to
`<input name="shooting" onChange={onChange} />`    

And 
`<button type="submit" className="submitButton" onClick={onChange}>`
to 
`<button type="submit" className="submitButton" onClick={() => calculateAvgRating(rating)}>`

Comment: You override your state every time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Number` instead of `parseInt`, as `Number('')` yields `0`. Also, console logging `total` right after setting it won't work, it'll only log the value from the *current* render cycle, not the one queued up for state update. You can instead just log the value you are updating state with.

```
const calculateAvgRating = ratingValues => {
  const {
    shooting,
    dribbling,
    ballcontrol,
    sprinting,
    fitness
  } = ratingValues;
  const newTotal =
    Number(shooting) +
    Number(dribbling) +
    Number(ballcontrol) +
    Number(sprinting) +
    Number(fitness);

  const finalAvg = newTotal / 5;
  setTotal(finalAvg);
  console.log("GGGGG:" + finalAvg);
};
```

Note, it's technically more correct to log as a side-effect, e.g. using an `useEffect` hook. Move the logging of `total` to an effect. This will log anytime the total value updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("GGGGG:" + total);
}, [total]);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-booth-e9n44?file=/src/App.js

i have add init value and fix some handle , check it out :D